# Best practices for storing secret keys

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

I have an asp.net app, and I want to store a machine wide encryption key that I will be using in the apps, when using DPAPI crypto system.

What are the best practices to store the key - where do I store it?

Thanks.

Comment: From whom do you need to keep the key a secret? End users? Server administrators? Fairies?

Comment: Watch those fairies, they are very sneaky.

Comment: The best method for storage of a secret depends entirely on who you are trying to keep the secret from.

Answer (score 3):

It very unsafe to store any key as plaintext in any non-volatile and inherently insecure medium (such as a Hard Drive). On such mediums, you should only store a signed encrypted version of a key, and write-access to the encrypted key should be secured.

The real work at hand is to model the security needs, to determine the key-management policy and implementation.

Comment: Thanks.
What i want to store is a file containing an encrypted key, so it can only be accessed by my applications in the specific app pool.
Also the process of creating that key is to have a pass phrase, and encrypt it using DPAPI and store it in the file i have mentioed.